# Is there any way to be notified when a garbage collection occurs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there anything like an event listener that I can add so I can execute a function whenever a GC occurs?

For example, if I simply wanted to log a line to the console on each GC, how can I do that?

I am fine with a Chrome-specific solution.

Comment: Interesting -- why do you want this?

Comment: A couple reasons - for one, I'd like to be able to see (in real-time) when GCs occur, along with used memory (which I'm currently logging with window.performance.memory).  Two - the application I'm writing will ideally have very little garbage created (and thus collected) - maybe a pipe dream, but if I get close to being successful I'll want to know every time a GC occurs, so I plan on logging them all to some persistent data store.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what GC is doing over a period of time, you can use the Profile tool in Chrome as described here:
[How can I log what is being garbage collected in my javascript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404510/how-can-i-log-what-is-being-garbage-collected-in-my-javascript-code)

It won't exactly put lines in your logs, but it might give you the info you need.

Comment: There is also a way to enable Chrome to allow access to JS data, as detailed in the articled linked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607184/what-is-chrome-doing-with-this-gc-event

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of (and learning more about) the Chrome profiler, but I really need to know when they're occurring when the site is in regular use.

Comment: So you need an event that is triggered on a garbage collection that will call an ajax method back to the server which will update a central log?  Or will logging on individual workstations do?

Comment: Ideally a generic callback where I can do whatever I want (log locally or make a REST call), but beggars can't be choosers!  Why, do you know of a way to log on the workstation?