# Chrome timeline slow GC events

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, garbage-collection

This screenshot is from my chrome extension. I'm just scrolling the screen up and down, and it keeps freezing. Looks like it's caused by garbage collection. How can I figure out **why** this is happening?

No code is running as far as I'm aware. I'm just scrolling the page. Why would it keep dumping **27MB** of memory every second!?

I can't take a heap snapshot because it takes forever, then actually crashes the plugin.

[image]

Comment: Here's a reference about what is Chrome doing with this “GC Event” may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607184/what-is-chrome-doing-with-this-gc-event

Comment: How can we _divine_ what's happening with your code if we don't have your code?

Answer (score 0):

Once it invokes GC, that means you are having something allocated on JS heap.

You can use heap profiler to find out what's that. Go to Profiles panel and use Record Heap Allocations tool.